# Add legendlabel to existing plot with legend

Tags: plotting, graphs-and-networks, legending

Problem: 
I have a plot with legend stored in a variable.

```
datatry=Table[{RandomReal[{0, 10}], RandomReal[{0, 10}]}, {i, 10}, {j, 3}];
plot = ListPlot[datatry, PlotLegends -> LineLegend[Table[i, {i, 5}]]]
```

This plot already has a legend as you can see below:
[image]

Now I want to change the variable 'plot' such that a label is added to the legend. I found a way to do this by replacing the entire linelegend part with a new linelegend and added plotlabel.

```
plot /. {LineLegend[
    List[Directive[PointSize[0.012833333333333334`], 
      RGBColor[0.368417`, 0.506779`, 0.709798`], 
      AbsoluteThickness[1.6`]], 
     Directive[PointSize[0.012833333333333334`], 
      RGBColor[0.880722`, 0.611041`, 0.142051`], 
      AbsoluteThickness[1.6`]], 
     Directive[PointSize[0.012833333333333334`], 
      RGBColor[0.560181`, 0.691569`, 0.194885`], 
      AbsoluteThickness[1.6`]], 
     Directive[PointSize[0.012833333333333334`], 
      RGBColor[0.922526`, 0.385626`, 0.209179`], 
      AbsoluteThickness[1.6`]], 
     Directive[PointSize[0.012833333333333334`], 
      RGBColor[0.528488`, 0.470624`, 0.701351`], 
      AbsoluteThickness[1.6`]], 
     Directive[PointSize[0.012833333333333334`], 
      RGBColor[0.772079`, 0.431554`, 0.102387`], 
      AbsoluteThickness[1.6`]], 
     Directive[PointSize[0.012833333333333334`], 
      RGBColor[0.363898`, 0.618501`, 0.782349`], 
      AbsoluteThickness[1.6`]], 
     Directive[PointSize[0.012833333333333334`], 
      RGBColor[1, 0.75`, 0], AbsoluteThickness[1.6`]], 
     Directive[PointSize[0.012833333333333334`], 
      RGBColor[0.647624`, 0.37816`, 0.614037`], 
      AbsoluteThickness[1.6`]], 
     Directive[PointSize[0.012833333333333334`], 
      RGBColor[0.571589`, 0.586483`, 0.`], AbsoluteThickness[1.6`]]], 
    List[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
    Rule[LegendMarkers, 
     List[List[False, Automatic], List[False, Automatic], 
      List[False, Automatic], List[False, Automatic], 
      List[False, Automatic], List[False, Automatic], 
      List[False, Automatic], List[False, Automatic], 
      List[False, Automatic], List[False, Automatic]]], 
    Rule[Joined, 
     List[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, 
      False, False]], Rule[LabelStyle, List[]], 
    Rule[LegendLayout, "Column"]] -> 
   LineLegend[
    List[Directive[PointSize[0.012833333333333334`], 
      RGBColor[0.368417`, 0.506779`, 0.709798`], 
      AbsoluteThickness[1.6`]], 
     Directive[PointSize[0.012833333333333334`], 
      RGBColor[0.880722`, 0.611041`, 0.142051`], 
      AbsoluteThickness[1.6`]], 
     Directive[PointSize[0.012833333333333334`], 
      RGBColor[0.560181`, 0.691569`, 0.194885`], 
      AbsoluteThickness[1.6`]], 
     Directive[PointSize[0.012833333333333334`], 
      RGBColor[0.922526`, 0.385626`, 0.209179`], 
      AbsoluteThickness[1.6`]], 
     Directive[PointSize[0.012833333333333334`], 
      RGBColor[0.528488`, 0.470624`, 0.701351`], 
      AbsoluteThickness[1.6`]], 
     Directive[PointSize[0.012833333333333334`], 
      RGBColor[0.772079`, 0.431554`, 0.102387`], 
      AbsoluteThickness[1.6`]], 
     Directive[PointSize[0.012833333333333334`], 
      RGBColor[0.363898`, 0.618501`, 0.782349`], 
      AbsoluteThickness[1.6`]], 
     Directive[PointSize[0.012833333333333334`], 
      RGBColor[1, 0.75`, 0], AbsoluteThickness[1.6`]], 
     Directive[PointSize[0.012833333333333334`], 
      RGBColor[0.647624`, 0.37816`, 0.614037`], 
      AbsoluteThickness[1.6`]], 
     Directive[PointSize[0.012833333333333334`], 
      RGBColor[0.571589`, 0.586483`, 0.`], AbsoluteThickness[1.6`]]], 
    List[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
    Rule[LegendMarkers, 
     List[List[False, Automatic], List[False, Automatic], 
      List[False, Automatic], List[False, Automatic], 
      List[False, Automatic], List[False, Automatic], 
      List[False, Automatic], List[False, Automatic], 
      List[False, Automatic], List[False, Automatic]]], 
    Rule[Joined, 
     List[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, 
      False, False]], Rule[LabelStyle, List[]], 
    Rule[LegendLayout, "Column"], LegendLabel -> "Label Legend"]}
```

Which gives:
[image]

Is there a simpler, easier way to do this?

Comment: LineLegend has an option for LegendLabel. PlotLegends -> 
 LineLegend[Table[i, {i, 5}], LegendLabel -> "Label Legend"
  ]

Comment: `plot /. LineLegend[a__] :> 
  LineLegend[a, LegendLabel -> "Label Legend"]`?

Comment: hm, you are using some functions here I didn't know yet

Comment: but it works. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
plot /. LineLegend[a__] :> LineLegend[a, LegendLabel -> "Label Legend"]
```

[image]

Comment: I have a graph with an existing `PlotLabel` and wanted to use this graph somewhere else with a new `PlotLabel`. How can I overwrite the existing label with a  new label?